# What schema is Gnome using

Tags: gnome, gconf, gsettings

Still trying to understand what schemas are, though it looks like Gnome loads from there the general data to configure the desktop. There are several in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`, but how to know what is the one that Gnome is using? Also, is there a command for Gnome to change to a different schema? `gsettings` and `gconf` seem to simply update the `xml` files, but I'm still missing the link to the alter the current schema.

I'm running Gnome 3.4.1 under an Ubuntu 12.04-based distro.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/glib-compile-schemas.html

Comment: https://projects.gnome.org/gconf/